# Looping xml files using glob function only loops the last file in the folder

Tags: php, simplexml

I've tried searching but couldn't really find an answer so I figured that I'd post a new question instead.

I have a folder with several xml files. I want to loop though all of these files.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
  $files = glob("visitkort/*xml");
    if (is_array($files)) {

     foreach($files as $filename) {
        $xmlstr = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
     }



    }
    $visitkort = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    foreach ($visitkort->person as $person) {
           echo '<article class="productInfo"><a href="redigera.php?id="><div> <p class="price">', $person->namn, '</p><p class="productContent">', $person->titel,  '</p></div></a> </article>', PHP_EOL;
        }

?>
```

Which works fine, except that it will only list the last file in the folder (e.g. I have three files named "1.xml", "2.xml" and "3.xml", only the info in the file "3.xml" will be listed) instead of all files.
What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Best regards,
Camilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorganize your code a bit, so the `foreach` loop deals with all three files.

```
<?php

$files = glob("visitkort/*xml");
if (is_array($files)) {

    foreach ($files as $filename) {
        $xmlstr = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
        $visitkort = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

        foreach ($visitkort->person as $person) {
            echo '<article class="productInfo"><a href="redigera.php?id="><div> <p class="price">', $person->namn, '</p><p class="productContent">', $person->titel, '</p></div></a> </article>', PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```